# Does renaming a GitHub organization affect the forks of that organization's projects?

Tags: git, github, github-organizations

I would like to rename a GitHub organization name, but some people have forks of some repositories of that organization.

If I rename it, this affects to the forks of the other people?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I remember: Github automatically changes the "source" of the fork after organization rename

Answer (score 3):

Forks hosted at Github will be ok. But all local clones that name your repository as an upstream must be updated to reflect the new name:

```
git remote set-url upstream http://github.com/newuser/newrepo.git  # or ssh://
```

Comment: Of Course, if I change the remote URL, I have to update the local repo config. Thanks for reminding me!